# Attempted to divide by zero Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to calculate average based on the sum of columns and how many there are.

Each movie can have a movierating, I'm trying to sum the movieratings together and then divide them by the amount of ratings to get the average rating for a movie.

```
(reviews.Where(w => w.MovieID == m.MovieID).Sum(o => o.MovieRating)) / reviews.Where(z => z.MovieID == m.MovieID).Count();
```

But the problem is if the count is 0. What can I do about it?

Comment: What is the desired result if there is no matching ID?

Comment: I see a 0/0 division here :-)

Comment: Just set it to null if there's no reviews.

Comment: and I see multiple enumeration also

Comment: Linq already has a [Average](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.average(v=vs.110).aspx) method

Comment: This is on both sides of your equation:  `reviews.Where(w => w.MovieID == m.MovieID)` - so can move it out do it once, and check if there are any before doing the actual calculation

Comment: How will you differentiate between a movie having no reviews, and a movie having a bunch of 0 reviews? Or is the lowest allowed review value greater than zero?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about using LINQs built in `Average` function?

```
reviews
    .Where(z => z.MovieID == m.MovieID)
    .Select(z => z.MovieRating)
    .DefaultIfEmpty(0)
    .Average()
```

To have the query fully run on the server (depending, I guess, on your database server):

```
reviews
    .Where(z => z.MovieID == m.MovieID)
    .Average(z => (decimal?)z.MovieRating) ?? 0
```

Comment: warn: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query[20500]
      The LINQ expression 'DefaultIfEmpty(__p_0)' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.

Comment: warn: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query[20500]
      The LINQ expression 'Average()' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.

Comment: `?? null` ?  Seriously?

Comment: @bonmelding `?? null` adds a `COALESCE` to the generated SQL, which on reflection, is not necessary in this case, I have removed it

Answer (score 5):

You could use

```
var ratingList = reviews
   .Where(z => z.MovieID == m.MovieID)
   .Select(z => z.MovieRating)
   .ToList();
if(ratingList.Count > 0)
{
   double result = ratingList.Sum() / ratingList.Count;
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to do it in a single roundtrip, totally SQL side (without downloading a lsit of reviews), if the `reviews` is a table on EF?

Comment: @xanatos: it is a single roundtrip, there's only one query and it's loaded into a list. The rest is done in memory.

Comment: You could add a `.Select(m => m.MovieRating)` before the `ToList`

Comment: @Tim If Reviews is a big row, you are downloading the whole row... If there are 1.000.000 rows, you are downloading 1,000,000 rows... What I men is, can I `SELECT COUNT(*), SUM(MovieRating) FROM Reviews WHERE MovieID = @MovieID` in EF? (this is just out of curiosity and probably outside the question of OP)

Comment: This is a solution that I had in mind as well (you beat me to it though) but it feels like there should something that we can do to optimize it.

Comment: @xanatos you can, but that would involve group by, like `Where(...).GroupBy(x => true).Select(...)`

Comment: @Evk Yes, found at https://stackoverflow.com/a/45144198/613130, written a response based on that.

Comment: @xanatos: i didn't download all 1.000.000 rows(as in your example) but only those reviews with matching `MovieID`

Comment: @TimSchmelter But they are reviews... Probably there aren't 1000000, but on a big site there could be 1000. And mine was only a curiosity... I didn't know the `GroupBy(x => true)` trick, and I wasn't able to write the query without. You were the most probable person that was looking at this page that could know it :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
double? score = reviews
   .Where(w => w.MovieID == m.MovieID)
   .Average(w => (double?) w.MovieRating)
   // ?? 0   // optional: pick a default when Average returns null
   ;
```

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto this answer has exactly the same amount of explanation as two upvoted answers.

Answer (score 0):

Just use Inline if condition like below:

```
var avr = (from a1 in reviews
           where a1.MovieID == m.MovieID
           group a1 by a1.MovieID into g
           select new
           {
               avr = g.count() == 0 ? 0 : g.sum(r => r.MovieRating) / g.count()
           }).FirstOrDefault().avr;
```

Answer (score -1):

I wanted to make a single query (because perhaps we are working on a DB, and each query has a cost "just because it is a query") and do all the computation SQL-side, so that I receive back a single row (because if there are 1000 reviews, I don't really need to download all of them... I want the sum of their `MovieRating` and their count).

```
// Based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/45144198/613130
var result = reviews
    .Where(x => x.MovieID == m.MovieID)
    .GroupBy(x => 1)
    .Select(x => ((double?)x.Sum(y => y.MovieRating)) / x.Count())
    .FirstOrDefault() ?? -1.0;
```

The `result` will be `-1.0` if there aren't reviews for the `MovieID`. Note the use of cast because otherwise we will have an integer division probably (if `MovieRating` is an integer).

Note that there won't be any division if a row isn't found (because there won't be any `Group`)

The equivalent query on a SQL database should be

```
SELECT CAST(SUM(x.MovieRating) AS FLOAT) / COUNT(*) 
    FROM Reviews x 
    WHERE x.MovieID = @MovieID 
    GROUP BY 1
```

But in truth the EF translated it in a much more complex way :-) (tested on EF 6.2.0):

```
SELECT 
    CAST( [GroupBy1].[A1] AS float) /  CAST( [GroupBy1].[A2] AS float) AS [C1]
FROM ( SELECT 
    [Filter1].[K1] AS [K1], 
    SUM([Filter1].[A1]) AS [A1], 
    COUNT([Filter1].[A2]) AS [A2]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        1 AS [K1], 
        [Extent1].[MovieRating] AS [A1], 
        1 AS [A2]
        FROM #Reviews AS [Extent1]
        WHERE [Extent1].[MovieId] = @p__linq__0
    )  AS [Filter1]
    GROUP BY [K1]
)  AS [GroupBy1]
```

Answer (score -1):

Not certain if there's a particular emphasis on use of LINQ, but I would prefer to put it all in a for/foreach loop rather than multiple LINQ. Otherwise below would work?

```
var matchingReviews = reviews.Where(w => w.MovieID == m.MovieID);
int matchingReviewCount = matchingReviews.Count();
if (matchingReviewCount  > 0)
{
    matchingReviews.Sum(o => o.MovieRating) / matchingReviewCount;
}
else
{
    //return default value?
}
```